# Минимальное и максимальное значение у input type datetime

Tags: html

мне нужно задать минимальное и максимальное значение который бы мог выбрать пользователь у input type datetime , подскажите как это сделать

Comment: Пример из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/datetime-local): `<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" min="2017-06-01T08:30" max="2017-06-30T16:30">`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    className="form-control mt-2"
    name="start_date"
    min="2022-02-21T20:20"
    max="2022-02-22T20:20"
/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , не знал )